# Looping Java switch statement

Tags: java

My system is a banking system and I want my program to loop after the user has interacted with one of the processes (withdraw, view balance etc).

After user get result I want to give a chance to continue with another process:

```
package smartcode.atm.h.w;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SmartCodeATMHW {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int p;
        int y = 1234;
        int Amount = 500;
        int result;
        int info;
        int f;
        int g;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter PIN Number ");
            p = in.nextInt();

            if (p == y) {
                System.out.println("You have entered correct PIN number \n\n*****************");

                profile pr = new profile();
                pr.setName("Prapashtica");
                System.out.println("Welcome mr." + pr.getName());

                //loop from here 
                boolean end = false;
                do{
                    System.out.println("\nPress 1 to View Bank Account");
                    System.out.println("Press 2 to Deposit money");
                    System.out.println("Press 3 to Withdraw money");
                    System.out.println("Press 4 to Cancle the Process \n\n********************");
                    info = in.nextInt();

                    switch (info) {
                        case 1:
                            System.out.println("You have  " + Amount + "$ available");
                            return;

                        case 2:
                            System.out.println("You have  " + Amount + "$ available");
                            System.out.println("Please enter the amount you wish to deposit");
                            f = in.nextInt();

                            result = Amount + f;
                            System.out.println("You have  " + result + "$ available");
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++) {
                                System.out.println("You have  " + Amount + "  $ available");
                                System.out.println("Please eter the amount you wish to withdraw");
                                g = in.nextInt();
                                if (g > 500) {
                                    System.out.println("You cannot withdraw more than your current amount");
                                } else {
                                    System.out.println("You have succesfully withdrawed  " + g + " $");
                                    result = Amount - g;

                                    System.out.println("You now have  " + result + "  $ available");
                                }
                            }
                            System.out.println("Your card is now blocked");
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            System.out.println("You have canceled the proccess");
                            break;
                        default:
                            System.out.println("Error \nInvalid number");
                            break;

                    }
                    return;
                }while (end == false);
            } else {
                System.out.println("You have entered incorrect PIN number  \nPlease try again  \n*******************************");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Your card is now blocked");
    }
}
```

Comment: `end` is never set to anything but `false` outside the loop..

Comment: I tried in many ways with for loop or while only but couldn't make it work so I tried this way.

Comment: Why do you `return` after the first iteration of the loop?

Comment: What's your concrete question/problem?

Comment: @tobias_k my mistake I dont really need that. I want to give the options again to the user after he has interacted with one of the processes

Answer (score 0):

I can see from the code you have already handled the requirement using end==false.

You need to remove the return; statement used after the switch case.

Also, for case 1 use break; instead of return;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int p;
    int y = 1234;
    int Amount = 500;
    int result;
    int info;
    int f;
    int g;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter PIN Number ");
        p = in.nextInt();

        if (p == y) {
            System.out.println("You have entered correct PIN number \n\n*****************");

            profile pr = new profile();
            pr.setName("Prapashtica");
            System.out.println("Welcome mr." + pr.getName());

            //loop from here 
            boolean end = false;
            do{
                System.out.println("\nPress 1 to View Bank Account");
                System.out.println("Press 2 to Deposit money");
                System.out.println("Press 3 to Withdraw money");
                System.out.println("Press 4 to Cancle the Process \n\n********************");
                info = in.nextInt();

                switch (info) {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("You have  " + Amount + "$ available");
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("You have  " + Amount + "$ available");
                        System.out.println("Please enter the amount you wish to deposit");
                        f = in.nextInt();

                        result = Amount + f;
                        System.out.println("You have  " + result + "$ available");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++) {
                            System.out.println("You have  " + Amount + "  $ available");
                            System.out.println("Please eter the amount you wish to withdraw");
                            g = in.nextInt();
                            if (g > 500) {
                                System.out.println("You cannot withdraw more than your current amount");
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("You have succesfully withdrawed  " + g + " $");
                                result = Amount - g;

                                System.out.println("You now have  " + result + "  $ available");
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.println("Your card is now blocked");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        System.out.println("You have canceled the proccess");
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Error \nInvalid number");
                        break;

                }

            }while (end == false);
        } else {
            System.out.println("You have entered incorrect PIN number  \nPlease try again  \n*******************************");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Your card is now blocked");
}
```

You can also take input from the User whether he wants to continue or not and depending on the response, display the options again.

Answer (score 0):

This here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
```

Around that other loop:

```
} while (end == false)
```

is simply bogus.

You want **one** loop that goes around your "menu"; and that loop ends when the user wants to end.

End of story.

Answer (score -1):

just put all cases into a infinite loop and when user select case 4 then system.exit(0); will terminate program otherwise it will loop.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    int p;
    int y = 1234;
    int Amount = 500;
    int result;
    int info;
    int f;
    int g;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter PIN Number ");
        p = in.nextInt();

        if (p == y) {
            System.out.println("You have entered correct PIN number \n\n*****************");

            profile pr = new profile();
            pr.setName("Prapashtica");
            System.out.println("Welcome mr." + pr.getName());

            //loop from here 
            boolean end = false;
            while(true){
                System.out.println("\nPress 1 to View Bank Account");
                System.out.println("Press 2 to Deposit money");
                System.out.println("Press 3 to Withdraw money");
                System.out.println("Press 4 to Cancle the Process \n\n********************");
                info = in.nextInt();

                switch (info) {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("You have  " + Amount + "$ available");
                        return;

                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("You have  " + Amount + "$ available");
                        System.out.println("Please enter the amount you wish to deposit");
                        f = in.nextInt();

                        result = Amount + f;
                        System.out.println("You have  " + result + "$ available");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++) {
                            System.out.println("You have  " + Amount + "  $ available");
                            System.out.println("Please eter the amount you wish to withdraw");
                            g = in.nextInt();
                            if (g > 500) {
                                System.out.println("You cannot withdraw more than your current amount");
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("You have succesfully withdrawed  " + g + " $");
                                result = Amount - g;

                                System.out.println("You now have  " + result + "  $ available");
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.println("Your card is now blocked");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        System.out.println("You have canceled the proccess");
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Error \nInvalid number");
                        break;

                }

            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("You have entered incorrect PIN number  \nPlease try again  \n*******************************");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Your card is now blocked");


}
```

}

Comment: see solution again

Comment: I want to continue the program after I finish the first case "Press 1 to View Bank Account" than I get the result, I want to program to give me the same options again.

Comment: why just not do simply with do-while statement? `do{....}while(in!=4);system.exit()`

Comment: yeah u can do this

Comment: if your application needs to run although  user press 4 then use return